# php mysql loop insert IP Address block

Tags: php, mysql, ip, ip-address

How can I insert 256 IP based on /24 block. if IP block is 192.168.1.0/24 & network is 192.168.1.0 so I want to create a loop to insert `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255` in mysql table . there will be a button when i press that it will insert 256 row 0 to 255.. Please help me to do it in php mysql

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['doSubmit'] ) && $_POST ['doSubmit'] == 'Submit Details') {
  // Filter POST data for harmful code (sanitize)
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $data [$key] = filter ( $value );
  }
  $network = $data [network]; // Is network ip 192.168.1.0
  // Action will go here
}
```

Comment: what expected input will be ?

Comment: `$data[network]` should be `$data['network']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i want to create a loop to insert 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255 in
>   mysql table

Generate like this...

```
foreach(range(0,255) as $val)
{
    $arr[]="192.168.1.".$val;
    //Running a query 255 times here is not a good idea !
}

//$arr now holds all your IPs , you could push it into your SQL Query..
```